# Disable default behaviour of Time Series MongoDB of creating compound index

Tags: mongodb, time-series

According to the official [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-secondary-index/) of Time Series MongoDB.

`Starting in MongoDB 6.3, MongoDB automatically creates a compound index on the metaField and timeField fields for new collections.`

Is their a way to disable this compound index creation behaviour?